# Using Knockoutjs to dynamically adapt page content to language selection by user?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, localization

I'm trying to use Knockoutjs to dynamically change the language/content of the labels on my webpage based on a language-selection made by the user in a dropdown.

At the moment I'm struggling with the syntax.
I've provided an example of my situation in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dWw7F/13/)

**What I can do:**

- Retrieve the value (id) of the selection.
- Retrieve/display the "chosen" label content from the languages array by manually inputting an index like this:

  ```
  self.chosenLang = languages[0];
  ```

**What I can't do:**

- Retrieve/display the "chosen" label content from the languages array by using the value (id) of the selection. Something like this:

  ```
  self.chosenLang = languages[self.selectedChoice];
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dWw7F/14/

What I've done is that I have added a subscription on the `selectedChoice` observable so that I can detect when it changes. A convenient thing with subscriptions are that they include the value of the publisher when subscribers gets called, hence the argument `choice` in the function.

```
self.selectedChoice.subscribe(function(choice) {
   self.chosenLang(languages[choice]);        
});
```

Then I promoted the `chosenLang` to an observable in order to make the DOM detect changes on it. This change also made me change the binding in the html, where I had to use this:

```
<p data-bind="text: chosenLang().q3"></p>
```

Note that the `chosenLang()` uses parenthesis. It is because we want to access the observables data and not the observable directly.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help! I actually tried to use a subscription at some point, but apparently I did something else wrong at the time.